# Sessions don't expire

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm trying to create a session for login that should expire after 2 minutes. The reason: I should create a page in our intranet that is accessible on public PCs in our production hall and if a user does not logout everyone else can see and interact with the whole page. Thats why I would like to keep this timespan close.
The problem is no matter what I do the session lasts several hours. I'm using Visual Studio with standart options to test it (I searched but I still dont know how to configurate the IIS timeout here)
Sofar I have tried in `Web.config`

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="2"/>
```

and `in some C# files`

```
Session["UserName"] = "test"; 
Session.Timeout = 1;
```

even something like

```
private DateTime start;
private DateTime end;
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["UserName"] = "test"; 
    Session.Timeout = 1;
    start = DateTime.Now;
}
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    end = DateTime.Now;
    var seconds = (end - start).TotalSeconds;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("session end " + seconds);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine((string)Session["UserName"]);
}
```

in `global.asax` does not work. Actually even after `Session_End` it still exists and is reachable. The `seconds` output is different in every test. Sometimes it is something like 1-10s sometimes it does not trigger after hours. I don't know when the session is finaly destoyed since I have only acces 6h a day in my company and when I debug the project in the morning, the session still exists 6h later.
Is there a method to check the remaining lifetime of a session (I searched here several hours but no code worked) or did I miss anything? I'm totally clueless since I had never problems with sessions in PHP, this is my first experience with ASP
Thank you very much
**Update**
problem solved, I didnt know my ajax request reset the timer everytime.

Comment: Session timeout means it will be abandoned *after certain time of inactivity*

Comment: yeah i know... so when I leave my workspace and go eating or something the session should be deleted. Or do I keep it alive when I ask if it still exists?

Comment: "The amount of time, in minutes, *allowed between requests* before the session-state provider terminates the session" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx). As long as the user doesn't initiate further HTTP requests to the server, it will be considered an inactivity

Comment: Ok thank you, seems like I have keept my session alive with Ajax requests because I reload new content from database every minute automatically. Is there a way to make an exception when the interaction/the request comes from Ajax or something like that?

Comment: do you have any kind of ajax that call the site and ask time to time for data? if yes this is the reason your session not expired, is refresed on each call

Comment: yes, I found that out 1 answer above^^ I solved the problem now